# Definite integration in mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to integrate the following in Mathematica.

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\cfrac{\text{e}^{\text{i}ax}}{x^2-b^2}\text{d}x$ where $a,b>0$

The analytical result is well known.

$-\cfrac{\pi}{b}\sin(ab)$

I used the following code

```
Integrate[E^(I a x)/(x^2 - b^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
 Assumptions->{a > 0, b != 0, b ∈ Reals}]
```

But Mathematica returned something else

```
-((π (I Abs[b] Cos[a b] + b Sin[a b]))/b^2)
```

How can I get the above analytical expression?

Comment: Well, if your assumption is that $b>0$, then why did you only specify `b != 0` in your assumptions to Integrate? Have you tried specifying that b is positive, rather than nonzero?

Comment: @MarcoB The assumptions should be fine. `b != 0 && b ∈ Reals` is equivalent to `b > 0` since the integral only has `b^2`.

Comment: @MarcoB : Yes I have used `Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, b \[Element] Reals}`. But then it fails to converge.

Comment: Solving the indefinite integral and then using limit gives `-((2 π Sin[a b])/b)`.

Comment: @JHM : Please provide the code..However why is the extra 2 coming?

Comment: Mathematica claims the integral diverges because, well, it diverges. So that's not a good way to get the Fourier transform of `1/(x^2-b^2)`. To get the FT one can do `In[14]:= FullSimplify[
 Sqrt[2*Pi]*
  FourierTransform[1/(x^2 - b^2), x, a, 
   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b != 0, Element[b, Reals]}]]

Out[14]= -((\[Pi] Sin[a b])/b)`

Comment: @JHM. Calculating the definite integral in that way in *Mathematica* can be dangerous. See, for instance, [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html#21924). There is an entire Wolfram blog post on this, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @march That blog is [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/). In this case the one sided limits at the pole will cancel, so it is in a sense "the right thing to do". Setting `PrincipalValue -> True` in the definite integral should also work, in theory, but it was taking more time than I wanted to wait so I aborted it.

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy The code is simply `f[y_] := (Integrate[E^(I a x)/(x^2 - b^2), x] /. x -> y); FullSimplify[Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0, Limit[f[x] - f[-x], x -> Infinity]]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes they're equal:

```
Block[{a = 2, b = 4},
 {NIntegrate[E^(I a x)/(x^2 - b^2),
   {x, -Infinity, -b - I, b + I, Infinity}],
  -((π (I Abs[b] Cos[a b] + b Sin[a b]))/b^2) // N}
 ]
(*
  {-0.77704 + 0.114275 I, -0.77704 + 0.114275 I}
*)
```

Kidding aside, perhaps you should specify `PrincipalValue -> True` (which I just noticed, belatedly, than [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) suggested in a comment).  After a cup of coffee, the following returns with the desired answer:

```
Integrate[E^(I a x)/(x^2 - b^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, b != 0, b ∈ Reals, x ∈ Reals}, PrincipalValue -> True]
(*
  -((π Sin[a b])/b)
*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Use of `PricipalValue` solves the problem.

Comment: Must have been one big cup, or else your computer is much faster than mine.

Answer (score 6):

This integral has not a value in Riemann's sense, then it has not a value  independent of your particular problem, as many people already commented above. Hence, it is better to use the residue theorem, and decide whether you want to include the residue from the pole at +b, at -b, both  ou none. Therefore:

```
rplus = Residue[E^(I a x)/(x^2 - b^2), {x, b}]
rminus = Residue[E^(I a x)/(x^2 - b^2), {x, -b}]
```

If you decide that the adequate solution includes both residues, your answer is

```
2 Pi I (rplus + rminus) // FullSimplify
```

which gives

```
-((2 \[Pi] Sin[a b])/b)
```

as you expect. Note, however, that (2 Pi I rplus), (2 Pi I rminus), and 0 can be acceptable values for this integral, depending on the specificities of your problem.